# count of comments by each user - mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose on facebook a user puts his status and then others comment on that status.
So, a situation like this evolves:

```
User 1 : My status 1
FB user 2: comment1
FB user 3: comment2
FB user 2: comment3
FB user 4: comment5

User 2 : My status 2
FB user 2: comment6
FB user 3: comment7

FB user 2: comment8
```

All this is stored in a table status_table as ID, Status, FB_User, Comment

Find the number of comments done by each user on a particular status.

For comments done by user2

```
select count(comments) from status_table group by ID
Where status="%Good%" AND user=user2;
```

This is my initial solution!!

The problem is I think it is right, but the interviewer rejected it.

Comment: we dont mind helping with homework, but noones going to write it for you.  Have a shot at it, then if you get errors show us what youve tried and the errors you got.

Comment: Added my initial solution. btw sorry for the delay.

Comment: @MattHB: Now, please have a look on it. and thanks for realising my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question says **each user** and not **a user**. So may be something like this:

```
select fb_user count(comments) from status_table 
  where status like '%[your particular status]%'
  group by fb_user;
```